# Raspberry Pi with 12V solenoid and 5V relay module

Tags: pi-3, power

I want to connect and control a 12V door lock solenoid and am a bit unsure about the circuit. So far I've bought following components in:

- Raspberry Pi 3 Model B
- 4x18650 Battery Holder
- 4x18650 (3.7V) Batteries as External Power Supply
- 1 channel 5V relay module
- 12V door lock solenoid

Is this sufficient? Or am I missing something? Im quite new and still learning in this field.

Please help out

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Do you happen to know make & model of the relay module (it is possible that it will not work with the Pi as its GPIO pins are 3.3 V not 5 V).

Comment: Yes @ghanima, its this one: https://www.elextra.dk/details/H40642/1-kanals-5v-relaemodul-til-arduino-pic-arm-avr-dsp

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a +5V switching regulator for the supply of the Raspberry Pi from your battery pack. The +12V may be unregulated, directly from the battery pack, though. The solenoid will work with anything from 10V to 16V.

---

But most important, you don't need a relay module for a door lock solenoid. These typically take 250mA@12V, which you can easily control with a darlington NPN transistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVd0i8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Don't miss the diode. It's needed to protect the transistor from the turn-off voltage spike the solenoid produces. The diode shorts that spike.

The ground is shared for +5V and +12V. The GPIO will never "see" those +12V, in case you wonder.

Comment: I do have a transistor just in case: N-MOSFET Transistor 100V 28A. Will this do the job along with a diode?

Comment: Yes? No? Without knowing the actual part number, this is impossible to say.