# How to connect Solenoid Lock to Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, camera, linux

Here is the scenario:
(We also have camera)

Here is the link for solenoid lock: [click here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B073DXLRYX)

1. When we run the our python code, camera will take an picture of QR code and it can get the QR code content
2. Now according to the QR code content. If content is "YES" we want to unlock the solenoid lock. Otherwise we want to unlock the solenoid lock.

Question is how to wire the solenoid lock to the raspberry pi 3 B+. I didn't find any image of video for wiring and also code.

And note that we have only solenoid and camera, do we need extra materials for unlocking or locking?

Comment: For a start maybe https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89516/raspberry-pi-with-12v-solenoid-and-5v-relay-module ? I actually get quite a few hits when searching for 'raspberry pi 12v solenoid', both on SE and elsewhere.

Comment: you really need to read what you wrote ..... i am pretty sure that is not what you meant to say